# How to connect to Azure Blob Storage using ManagedIdentityCredential

Tags: java, azure-managed-identity

Currently I have a simple code to list files on Azure storage container using a connection string:

```java
String connectStr = "<CONNTECTION_STRING>";
              
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(<CONTAINER_NAME>);
System.out.println("Listing files in container:");
for (BlobItem blobItem : containerClient.listBlobs()) {
    System.out.println("\t" + blobItem.getName());
}
```

I'm trying to update the code to authenticate using ManagedIdentityCredential:

```java
ManagedIdentityCredential managedIdentityCredential = new ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(<MANAGED_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID>)
                .build();
```

But I'm not sure how to replace the managedIdentityCredential into BlobServiceClient...

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the managedIdentityCredential you can create a BlobServiceClient instance using the credential method in BlobServiceClientBuilder:

```java
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().credential(managedIdentityCredential).buildClient();
```